# Jetbrains PyCharm with Enthought Canopy

Tags: pycharm, enthought, canopy

New to `Python` and I have been trying different IDE's and `Python` distributions. So far I've used the Jetbrains IDE's, and it seems like the most mature IDE of them all.

The people in the project like the scientific distributions (Continum IO, and Enthought). I'm leaning towards Enthought, since the `netCDF` libraries are packaged for all platforms.

Wondering what the trick is to get PyCharm to Python Environment in Canopy?
Using both Mac and Windows.

Tried the paths listed here:
https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-

but the Dialog says the `pyvenv.cfg` is not a proper Python SDK.
Tried also the `Python.exe` in the scripts directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case (mac) the interpreter path is:

~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/bin/python

I also had some trouble getting PyCharm and Canopy to work well together when Canopy was new.  Now with version 1.3 I haven't had trouble -- the two work together seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new project, you need to locate where you installed enthought, and link the `Python.exe` to the interpreter box shown below:

[image]